# Shortcuts - Saving a file to specific folder that is NOT ‘/shortcuts/‘

Tags: icloud, shortcut-menu, shortcuts-app, files.app

I’m trying to create a shortcut from the sharesheet to save a file to particular iCloud Drive/Files folder. However within the options for the ‘save file’ action in shortcuts only allows me to save into the directory ‘/shortcuts/‘. How do I change this so that I can specify a file path that is not within ‘/shortcuts/‘?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't access files outside `/Shortcuts/` *on purpose*, it's called sandboxing and makes sure that your iCloud data is safe!

As a matter of fact, it *used to be* possible to trick Shortcuts.app with a relative path (e.g. `/Shortcuts/../../hiddenData/`), but that security problem (CVE-2019-7289) was fixed in February 2019: [release notes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209522)

Comment: Protecting you from...yourself.

Comment: Thank you for these responses, I realise the security implications of this now. I heard one of the hosts of The Automators Podcast uses Hazel to then move files from the Shortcuts folders to others on their computer as a workaround. Unfortunately I can't remember the specific episode to link to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can save files to folders on iPhone/iPad in the latest version of Shortcuts.  Using Save File under the Documents Actions and enable Ask Where to Save.  You can also save using Share under the Share Actions.

Comment: Which version are you talking about?

Comment: I can’t find the version number in App Store or Settings / Apps.  It is updated (no Update button).  I think this feature has been around for a while: Set “Ask Where to Save” and you can select a local folder.